# Java: Using the same scanner variables to store multiple sets of entries

Tags: java

Is there a way to use the same prompt yet store the users data again without creating a second variable? It all needs to displayed at the same time in a table like fashion (hence the tabs)

```
//Variables
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        int num = 1;
        int group = 10, string = 12, formatting = 8;



        while (num <= 3)

        {




        System.out.print("Please enter name of assignment 1: ");
        String assignment = user.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.print("Please enter points earned: ");
        double earned = user.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter total points possible: ");
        double total = user.nextDouble();

        }

    System.out.print(assignment + "\t\t"); 
    System.out.print(earned + "\t"); 
    System.out.print(total + "\t\t"); 
    System.out.print(percent.format(earned / total) + "\n\t");


 when looping it is skipping the "Please enter name of assignment prompt:

    Please enter name of assignment 2: Please enter points earned: 



I expected the output to be:

    Please enter name of assignment 1: Practice Exam
    Please enter points earned: 89
    Please enter total points possible: 125

    Please enter name of assignment 2: FooBar
    Please enter points earned: 42
```

Comment: What you have posted does not look like an error message, Can you provide the specific error message the console gave?

Comment: `String assignment = user.nextLine().toUpperCase();;` why got two semicolon here? is it typo or what?

Comment: No error message sorry let me rephrase, when looping it is skipping the "Please enter name of assignment prompt\

Comment: can you please add your expected out put in your question

Comment: `user` isn't declared.

Comment: You need to show more code, specifically, the loop construct (`for` or `while`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're consuming the numbers but you're not consuming the newlines

try this

```
    String assignment;
    String exit=null;
    double earned, total;
    int i = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(exit)) {
        i++;
        System.out.print("Please enter name of assignment " + i + ": ");
        assignment = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase(); //consumes string + \n
        System.out.print("Please enter points earned: ");
        earned = scan.nextDouble();//consumes double
        scan.nextLine();//consumes \n
        System.out.print("Please enter total points possible: ");
        total = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Assignment\t");
        System.out.print("Score\t");
        System.out.print("Total       Points\t");

        System.out.print(assignment + "\t\t");
        System.out.print(earned + "\t");
        System.out.println(total + "\t\t");

        System.out.print("Stop?(Y/N)");
        exit = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

returns

```
Please enter name of assignment 1: 1
Please enter points earned: 1
Please enter total points possible: 1
Assignment  Score   Total       Points  1       1.0 1.0     
Stop?(Y/N)n
Please enter name of assignment 2: 2
Please enter points earned: 2
Please enter total points possible: 2
Assignment  Score   Total       Points  2       2.0 2.0     
Stop?(Y/N)y
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the results in a temp variable to add up later?

Comment: sure, you can accumulate the values into lists (see java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: double[] calc; calc = new double[4];   
          calc[i] = earned; // Array elements coincide with the current iteration loop

Comment: if you know how much iterations, you can use an array. If you don't, you can use a list (dynamic array)