# Duplicate output

Tags: java, io, console

Why `Number lower than 9` is printed twice in my console, in the bellow code example?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    System.out.println("Input from keyboard should be '49'");
    char e;
    for (int a = 0; ; a++) {
        e = (char) System.in.read();
        if (e == 49)
            break;
        else
            System.out.println("Use number lower than 9");
    }
}
```

And here is the output when you type anything except of number 1:

```
run:
Input from keyboard should be '49'
2
Number lower than 9
Number lower than 9
```

### Edit

Basicly, I am trying to get an input from console and store it inside `char e`. What I'm getting after I type `1` is value `49`. That's why I used in code above `e == 49`. I dont know how to retrieve just character `1`. Next thing is that i used an infinite loop to force the input to ask for specific character until its the correct one.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949775/java-using-the-same-scanner-variables-to-store-multiple-sets-of-entries/21950307#21950307

Comment: You never print "Number lower than 9" in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter `2` in the command line, you actually enter `2\n` (with `\n` being the newline character), as you confirm your input by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>.

`System.in.read()`  therefore returns a `2` in the first loop cycle and the newline character in the second loop cycle, each time printing your message on the standard output.

You can solve this by skipping newline characters:

```
for (int a = 0; ; a++) {
    e = (char) System.in.read();
    if (e == '\n')
        continue;
    if (e == 49)
        break;
    else
        System.out.println("Use number lower than 9");
}
```

There are some more issues though: What are you trying to achieve? if you compare the input on a character-based level, `49` equals not to the number 49, but to the character with the code 49, which is the character `'1'`.

Secondly, if you are building an endless loop, you should also write it that way. A for loop gives the impression, the loop will be left based on your `int a`, which is not the case. To write an endless loop, you can just write:

```
while (true) {
    // do something
    if (checksomething())
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    System.out.println("Input from keyboard should be '49'");
    char e;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    for (;;) {
        e = s.next().charAt(0);
        if (e == 49){
            System.out.println("Yay");
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Use number lower than 9");
        }
    }
}
```

You can just scan for the string but if u need chars the code above works

Answer (score 0):

Your program output showing **Number lower than 9** because it `System.in.read()` returns the ASCII value of first character entered that is '2' and its not 49 its 50.

If you want integer as input you can use this code  `int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();`

Refer this [Question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273449/what-does-system-in-read-actually-return)

Answer (score 0):

> read() doesn't read a number, it reads one byte and returns its value
>   as an int. If you enter a digit, you get back 48 + that digit because
>   the digits 0 through 9 have the values 48 through 57 in the ASCII
>   encoding.

[source](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/287979-how-to-use-systeminread/)

```
for (;;) {
    int e = System.in.read(); // char e = (char)System.in.read();
    if (e == 49) // if (e == '1')
        break;
    else
        System.out.println("You entered something else than character 1");
}
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is counted as a character, hence another character entry.

If you want to store **just** character `1`, there is no point of casting it.

```
    if (e == 49) {
       //Presume that is character `1` and do what operation you want as it is.
       System.out.println("You enter number 1");
    }
```

Instead you should check for correct input and then cast it to character. You can check the input if is number *as I wrote in the quote* by checking the input if is between `48` and `57`. **Remember, if you type e.g. 57 is counted as two inputs(5 and 7)** .

```
    char ch; int e;
    if (e >= 49 && e <= 57) {
       ch = (char)e;
       System.out.println("You enter number " + ch);
    }
```

---

This all can been done easily with `Scanner.nextInt()` *as others mentioned* which casts,and spots easily the next int number, **but be careful** ,`Scanner` works differently ,it checks tokens *rather than characters*, meaning delimiter would be by default an *empty space* (`" "`). So if you type `57` (and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) it will cast it to number `57`.

The convenience is that if you type `dogs 57` (and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) it will still gets as an input `57` and skip `dogs`. Another convenient method is `hasNextInt()`, so you can use it inside a `while` loop to get several number inputs.

You can also change the delimiter `useDelimiter()`, if you want to get it's character, set it to `("")` *empty string*.